# Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' -> A UserDetailsService must be set

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security

I'm currently struggle to get a project running from another person, where I upgraded the maven project to version 2.5.0. Would be great if somebody can give me a hint, what I miss. I used a higher version, but downgraded due to another issue I faced with the extension of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but it's a different story. Right now, I would like to get the login working.

Short version of my log entries:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' defined in class path resource com/shop/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:85) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar!/:5.5.0]
```

**WebSecuriyConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void setMyUserDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
    this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/product/**","/","/home**","/user/**","/registration**","/products**","/default**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**","/bower_components/**","/js/**","/css/**","/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/cabinet**","/principle/**" ).authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority(String.valueOf(Role.ADMIN))
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
            .successForwardUrl("/default")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("pass").roles(String.valueOf(Role.USER)).and()
            .withUser("admin").password("pass").roles(String.valueOf(Role.ADMIN));
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
            = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

**MyUserDetailsService.java**

```
    @Service
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        LOG.info("Finded user : [" + username + "]");
        return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
    }


    public class MyUserPrincipal extends User implements UserDetails {
        private User user;

        private MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRole().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return user.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return user.getUsername();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return user.getIsAccountNonLocked();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks ahead.

Cheers,
Marcel

Comment: what does your folder/file structure look like

Comment: The project imported directly via eclipse / github (Projects from Git).
Structure is shown in the linked image --> https://imgur.com/a/w1HFRbr

Comment: the image does not show where the classes above are located in relation to eachother, you have just posted a bunch of packages

Comment: the main class will search recursively from its location and beneath it in subfolders for all classes to find for potential injection. If you have your main class in a sub package it ill not find classes in other side packages. Its recommended to have the main class in the root folder so it can search recursivly through all folders